# Error page when someone accesses Application.cfc

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, application.cfc

I am just considering a scenario where someone might give Application.cfc in a url. I know this will not work as it is reserved by ColdFusion engine and user will see an error.

Is it possible to redirect user in such scenario?

Comment: Sure, but you have to do it using web-server rewriting before it hits ColdFusion server. You should update your question with web-server details to receive more specific answer.

Comment: On the other hand, why would `normal` user try to access the Application.cfc..? It is protected already, so I don't think it makes much sense to bother about something else.

Comment: Thanks for the response Sergii. What server details should I put on?
Also, I was thinking about scenario where no matter what user types in if it is not a valid url, it should be redirected to error page rather than blue CF error screen.

Comment: I just ran it on a CF9.01 server and I got `HTTP 500 Internal Server Error`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just successfully caught it with a site-wide error handler.  Is that a viable solution for you?

Small update, figured this out:

```
<cftry>
    <cfif error.Message EQ "Invalid request of Application.cfm, Application.cfc, or OnRequestEnd.cfm file.">
        <cflocation url="#getContextRoot()#/#getDirectoryFromPath(error.Template)#">
    </cfif>
    <cfcatch>that didn't work</cfcatch>
</cftry>
```

Comment: I tried following code, but it is still not hitting onError()

<cffunction name="onError" access="public" returntype="void" output="true">
  <cfargument name="Exception" required=true/>
     <cfargument type="String" name = "EventName" required=true/>
  <cfdump var="#arguments#"><cfabort> </cffunction>

Comment: You can't catch this particular error in the onError method of Application.cfc.  Apparently the error is thrown prior to Application.cfc being loaded, so no chance for onError() to run.  You need to catch it in the site-wide error handler.  You would configure this in ColdFusion Administrator, Server Setting->Settings->Site-wide Error Handler.

Answer (score 1):

I think CF intercepts the call to application.cfc, application.cfm and onrequestend.cfm at a position where you can grab the error.

I just did some testing on one of my coldfusion development sites and brought the application.cfc up a parent folder before the defined IIS website home folder and tried to call the file.  It returned a 404 error for file not found.  Since coldfusion searches up to the root folder to find the file, it will still find your application.cfc file even though its not in an IIS accessible folder.  IIS will turn your 404 error for direct requests.

Handling your 404 error maybe the solution.

I assume this would also be a solution for non windows server environments as well.

Answer (score 1):

Well: you should handle this sort of error the same way you handle any uncaught error on your website: leave it to the [`onError()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7d4a.html) handler / [`<cferror>`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7d29.html) code / [site-wide error template](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Admin/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbf3638e6-7ffc.html). As you're using Application.cfc, onError() is the best approach here.

This sort of error doesn't need special handling, but unhandled errors of *any* type should be dealt with appropriately. If you're not doing this (it sounds like you're not), you ought to be.

Comment: My attempt on using onError() in the Application.cfc didn't work.  I'm assuming that the error is thrown before Application.cfc gets executed.  This is at the top of the stack trace: coldfusion.filter.ApplicationFilter$ReservedTemplateException: Invalid request of Application.cfm, Application.cfc, or OnRequestEnd.cfm file. at coldfusion.filter.ApplicationFilter.invoke(ApplicationFilter.java:109) at coldfusion.filter.RequestMonitorFilter.invoke(RequestMonitorFilter.java:48) at

Comment: Oh yeah, that's a good point! I guess the site wide error approach @barry mentions is the way to go.